# How to update html table with primefaces poll

Tags: primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5. I want to update html table td with `p:poll` update but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="someForm">
    <p:panel id="somePanel" >
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="dontUpdate" value="#{backingBean.menuParam}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="iv1" itemLabel="il1"/>
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="iv2" itemLabel="il2"/>
                        <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" global="false" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText id="ot1" value="#{backingBean.ot1}" styleClass="otClass"
                                  rendered="#{backingBean.someProperty}"/>
                    <h:outputText id="ot2" value="#{backingBean.ot2}" styleClass="otClass"
                                  rendered="#{!backingBean.someProperty}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:outputText id="ot3" value="#{backingBean.ot3}"/>
                    <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{backingBean.pollListener}" 
                            update="ot3 ot1 ot2" global="false" binding="#{poll}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

I want to update `h:outputText` fields (ot1, ot2 and ot3) but don't update `p:selectOneMenu`. But this code only updates "ot3" and doesn't update "ot1" or "ot2".
How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi i just copy and past, it is working fine. it update all text ot1,2,3.
I think your poll is working, might your output text will same for each time.
Can you put more code.

Comment: You can chnage this update="ot3 ot1 ot2" with update="ot3, ot1, ot2", you miss the comma i think

Comment: no, it doesnt work